# How to return lines that have a specific word only

Tags: python

Running a simple program that accepts two inputs, an input file, and a word to search for. It then should print out all lines that contain the word. For example, my input file contains 5 sentences as follows:

```
My cat is named garfield
He is my first Cat
My mom is named cathy
This is a catastrophe
Hello how are you
```

The word I want to check for is cat

This is the code I wrote:

```
input_file = sys.argv[1]
input_file = open(input_file,"r")
wordCheck = sys.argv[2]

for line in input_file:
    if wordCheck in line:
        print line

input1.close()
```

Now obviously, this will return lines 1, 3, and 4, because they all contain "cat" at some point. My question is, how would I work it so that only line 1 (the only line with just the word "cat") would be printed?

Second question is, what would be the best way to get all lines that had the word "cat" in them, disregarding case. So in this situation, you would return lines 1 and 2, because they contain "cat" and "Cat" respectively. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put break after the print line for the first case

Comment: Just get yourself familiar with regular expressions and they will change your life.

Comment: you might want to consider the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) module.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for that:

```
import re

# '\b': word boundary, re.I: case insensitive 
pat = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(wordCheck), flags=re.I)

for line in input_file:
    if pat.search(line):
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short way of doing it, use `in` on a list of words instead of string directly.

```
word = 'cat'
for line in lines:
    if word in line.split(' '): # use `in` on a list of all the words of that line.
        print(line)
```

Outputs:
`My cat is named garfield`

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can use `break` statement to stop the loop after getting the first match

```
for line in input_file:
    if wordCheck in line.split(' '):
        print line
        break # add break here
```

For your second question, you could user `lower()` function to convert everything into lower case, so that `Cat` and `cat` would be detected.

```
for line in input_file:
    if wordCheck in line.lower().split(' '):
        print line
```